# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16f2dbfd0) what does this code mean>

Tags: ios, swift, class, inheritance, error-handling

I'm trying to create a variable containing a class from another view controller, but this error is popping up after running my app, on the `var char = Characters()` line. The code works if I did all the code in one view controller, but I'm trying to create a switch statement (A very long one) on a different view controller, and then just call the switch statement whenever I need it, on the primary view controller. my code from both `viewcontrollers` goes as follows

```swift
class ProgressBrain: UIViewController {
  
    var char = Characters()
    var level = 0
    var toNextLevel = 1
    var xpGained = 0.1
    
    func nenuLeveling() {
        var nenuProgress = char.nenuProgress.progress
        var nenuLevel = char.nenuLevel.text
        
        switch nenuLevel {
        case "1":
            nenuProgress = 0.0
            
            toNextLevel += 3
            nenuLevel = "2"
        case "2":
            
            xpGained = 1
            toNextLevel += 3
            nenuLevel = "3"
        case "3":
           
            xpGained = 1
            toNextLevel += 3
            nenuLevel = "4"
        default:
            print("Something went wrong")
        }
    }
   
}

class Characters: UIViewController {

    
    var pb = ProgressBrain()
    var toNextLevel = 10
    var xpGained = 1
    var nenuEx = 1
    var nenuSurvival = 5
   
    
    
    @IBOutlet var nenuProgress: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet var remfoProgress: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet var oneiroProgress: UIProgressView!
    
   
    @IBOutlet var nenuLevel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet var nenuTab: UITabBarItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var selector: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var characterImg: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet var routine: UIView!
    var views: [UIView]!
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
       
    }

  
    
    @IBAction func progressButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
      nenuProgressButton()
    }
    
   
    func nenuProgressButton() {
   
       
        
        let percentageProgress = Float(xpGained) / Float(toNextLevel)
        
        if xpGained < toNextLevel + 1{
    
        
        nenuProgress.progress = Float(percentageProgress)
        print(Float(percentageProgress))
        
          xpGained += 1
            
    } else if xpGained == toNextLevel + 1 {
     
        pb.nenuLeveling()
     
        nenuProgress.progress = 0.0
        xpGained -= toNextLevel
        
       
    }
}
```

Comment: `var char = Characters()` means `var char = Characters.init()`, that mean you don't provide the XIB or the storyboard associated for its initialization. So all your IBOutlet will be nil. Same for `var pb = ProgressBrain()`. And these are new instances, new objects, not the one you see on screen( I guess).

Comment: You also have `Characters` instantiating a new `ProgressBrain` and `ProgressBrain` is instantiating a new `Characters`, and you're going to end up with an endless recursion of each instantiating the other repeatedly. In order to suggest a fix, you need to describe outline the relationship between these two view controllers and their respective view hierarchies. Is one a child view controller of the other with both visible at the same time? Is one presenting the other?

Comment: (As an aside, we would generally give our view controller classes names that indicate that they are, indeed, view controllers, to make it easier to reason about our code. E.g., `ProgressBrainViewController` and `CharactersViewController`.)

Comment: For general information, see [Understanding the Exception Types in a Crash Report](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/understanding-the-exception-types-in-a-crash-report), [Investigating Memory Access Crashes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/investigating-memory-access-crashes/), [Identifying the Cause of Common Crashes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/identifying-the-cause-of-common-crashes), etc. But, as Larme said, the problem is that `Characters` was not instantiated from storyboard, and therefore the `@IBOutlet`s not being hooked up.

Comment: Can you post images that shows what you wanna achieve?